# iOS Custom UITextField with outlet initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I need `UITextField` with little customization. 
I've created new custom class CustomTextField. In IB I created `outlet` for each of my custom `UITextField`. I run the code and customization was not working.

To make check I put breakpoint on initialization procedure `initWithFrame` in the custom `UITextField`. The breakpoint was not hit. I suppose that additional `init` must be made in each View Controller, but I am not sure what exactly.

As I created outlet I suppose that `init` will be made automatically, but because this is a custom class it must be `init` manually with construction like that:

```
CustomTexTField *textField = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:customFrame];
[self.view addSubView:textField];
```

So do I need additional `init` in each View controller and how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing a view from IB or a storyboard, `initWithCoder` is the initializer used, not `initWithFrame`, and is why the breakpoint is not being hit. Put the customization code in the `initWithCoder` method. E.g.:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        // Put customization code here...

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: 10x. It works! So to summarize, if I understand properly: when creating `UITextField` from the code I use `initWithFrame`, in the other case (when it is defined in the `.xib` file I use `initWithCoder`).

Comment: Your statement on when to use `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder` is generally true for `UIView` and subclasses thereof. In addition, there are other initializers for some subclasses, such as `initWithImage` for `UIImageView`, that should be considered as well.

Comment: 10x, again. You help me a lot!